# Como usar Filtros no Doctrine?

Tags: doctrine, slim, doctrine-2

tenho as Entidades que fiz no Doctrine, e também tenho as DAOS, que é onde ficam essas consultas.

Tenho uma API onde o usuário podem ou não usar Query Parameters da seguinte forma:

> https://minha-api.com/usuarios/?idade=19

A consulta retorna tudo mas se usuário colocar esse parâmetro ai "idade=19", vai retornar apenas os usuários que tem idade = 19, para mim seria fácil jogar isso em um WHERE, mas seria muito trabalhoso, principalmente se o for passado muitos parametros.

Tem alguma outra forma de fazer isso usando o Doctrine ?

Tentei usar Filtros mas achei a documentação um pouco confusa alguém pode me ajudar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver esse problema utilizei o doctrine filter collection.

link: https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/collections/criteria-collection-filtering